# JS how to check if webpage has been added as homepage?

Tags: javascript, set

I am trying to make something similar like Google on IE. They create a "Make Google your homepage" script for IE.

This is what I have so far:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#no_thanks").click(function () {
$(".lightbar").hide();
}); });
</script> 

<!--[if IE]>
<div class="lightbar">Come here often? Make xxx your homepage.
<span class="sure"><a href="#" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('http://www.xxx.com');_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'HomePage', 'Sure', 'Set as Home page']);">Sure!</a></span>
<span class="nothanks"><a id="no_thanks" href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'HomePage', 'No', 'Set as Home page']);">No Thanks</a></span>
</div>
<![endif]-->
```

I also added some Google Analytics.

What happens is that the script works, it does set the homepage, but the `"lightbar"` doesn't disappear when I restart the browser (i'm not talking about the jQuery script).

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're only hiding it when they click on #no_thanks. I don't see where you're trying to hide it when they click 'Sure!'

Comment: sure, but if i restart the web browser, even if the webpage has been set to my webpage the "lightbox" will still show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Imho there is no solid way**.

the best you could do is to add a **querystring** to the url that is under the **add-as-homepage link**. like:

```
www.example.com/homepage.html?isbookmark=true
```

or

```
www.example.com/homepage.html?ishomepage=true
```

then just check **if the querystring exists** in the url when the document is called. Then it is initiated from this button or a bookmark or a homepage.

Comment: This won't catch people that directly bookmark your site rather than use your link. Overall, any way you do this will have some shortcomings as browsers don't really have access to get this sort of information.

Comment: @robert indeed, my answer is just an attempt

Comment: Right, wasn't for you, your way is a good way, but there is no completely correct answer